# UnavailableError: 7 root error(s) found and using TPU I am getting this error.How to resolve it

Tags: python, deep-learning

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/content/drive/My Drive/Covid-Detection-using-Lung-Xray-Images-master/cdac/Saved/Checkpoint/modelfinal0_100.{epoch:02d}.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                               monitor = 'val_loss')
csv_logger = CSVLogger('/content/drive/My Drive/Covid-Detection-using-Lung-Xray-Images-master/cdac/Saved/Log/model0.log')

history=model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs = 20,
    callbacks=[csv_logger, checkpointer])

model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/Covid-Detection-using-Lung-Xray-Images-master/cdac/model/model_final_100v2.hdf5', overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True)
```

after running this in google collab I am getting an error. I used TPU to run this program which is related to Covid19 detection using X-Ray lung images. It has 3 classes namely normal,Pneumonia and Covid. I used the drive to prepare data and extract the zip file earlier in this code. The file path is correctly given. Help, please. Thanks in advance

**ERROR:**

```
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnavailableError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ae8b80faaa4d> in <module>()
     10     validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
     11     epochs = 20,
---> 12     callbacks=[csv_logger, checkpointer])
     13 
     14 model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/Covid-Detection-using-Lung-Xray-Images-master/cdac/model/model_final_100v2.hdf5', overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True)

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

UnavailableError: 7 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_41676}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1597873146.970016559","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1597873146.808044681","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[strided_slice_57/_252]]
  (1) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_41676}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1597873146.970016559","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1597873146.808044681","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[strided_slice_91/_288]]
  (2) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_41676}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1597873146.970016559","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1597873146.808044681","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[strided_slice_126/_166]]
  (3) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_41676}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1597873146.970016559","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1597873146.808044681","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_4505907264126063010/_4/_238]]
  (4) Unavailable: {{function_n ... [truncated]
```

Comment: Did you solve it?